# data from word to excel

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

Hai ,
     I have a word file with n number of employee address in it... Now i want to convert it to an excel file... I am using windows xp.. Is there a way to do so?

name
streetname
area
city
contactno

name
streetname
area
city
contactno

Comment: what is the format of 1 employee address? All on 1 line? Edit your question with a sample of address.

Comment: Please add a screeny from your word file.

Comment: And what version of Office?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Word, reformat the data to be tabular - each field separated by tabs, each record on a separate line:

1. Press Ctrl+H to bring up the Find & Replace window.
2. In the "Find what" box, type `^p^p`, and in the "Replace with" box, type `^l`. Press the Replace All button. [This replaces any two consecutive paragraph marks with a line break. It assumes that your records are separated by a blank row, which is what it looks like in your example.]
3. Now type `^p` in the Find what box, and `^t` in the Replace with box, then Replace All. [This replaces any remaining (single) paragraph marks with tab characters.]
4. Probably optional, but just for completeness, type `^l` in Find what, and `^p` in Replace with, then Replace All. [This replaces the line breaks from step 2 with paragraph marks.]

Now you can simply copy & paste the data into Excel.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to select all the document in Word (Edit > Select All), copy and paste it directly in an Excel spreadsheet. Doing it, each row in word will become a row in excel. Then you could select each block in excel and then paste special/transpose it.

Another way is edit your word document, in order to have your records in one line (just join the lines, using a ";" to separate the fields. Then save the document as TXT and import it in Excel.